# xslt: get attribute from xsl itself

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

is it possible to read an xsl attribute from the xsl document itself? I need something like this:

mystyle.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    id="I'm a special stylesheet">

    ...
    <!-- Output should be: "stylesheet id: I'm a special stylesheet" -->
    <xsl:text>stylesheet id:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/@id"/>
    ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `<xsl:value-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/@id"/>`, at least as long as the stylesheet has been loaded from a URI.